# Setting width=device-width in viewport breaks layout

Tags: iphone, html, ios, css, mobile

I have a layout that is supposed to scale based on the device's width using `@media` queries in the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
    ....
}
```

While the style does appear to be applied, once the viewport is set to "width=device-width", the design effectively breaks. Probably because it is too narrow , which is strange as the CSS is supposed to scale everything down.

Check the Screen below

[image]

Quick edit: Seems to work on Android 4.1 somehow.

Comment: You actually shouldn't set the viewport to device width at all, at least if you want to support the iPhone 5 as well. Check out [this article](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers) about dealing with the viewports and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a problem on iPhone? It might be because of the double pixel size of the phone retina display, try adding `initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0` to the viewport content.